# WP REST API can't set post tags

Tags: rest-api

I create post with WP REST API but can't set tags for the post.

```
var post_data = {
    'author': 1,
    'title': 'My title',
    'content': 'My content',
    'status': 'publish',
    'tags': ['tags1','tags2'],
}
```

That code return error: `Invalid parameter(s): tags`

Can you explain wheres wrong?

Comment: How are you posting this request? Are you setting `tags` to the slugs or IDs? (you should use IDs instead of slugs)